# CSS Flash Object Positioning

Tags: css, flash, shockwave

I'm trying to properly position my embedded Shockwave Flash object on my HTML page in such a way that it will take 70% of the page's width. However, this element seems to also rely heavily on a specified height as well (which struck me as odd since image tags can use the width attribute without a specified height, in which case it would re-scale the image based on aspect ratio). My problem is that when the page's width is narrow enough, I get unpleasant white spaces above and below the embedded object. Is there a way to fix this problem in CSS, or is this an issue I should address in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Css should address this, use a div inside of a div and scale outer outer div and keep inner div 100% with min-height 1px, or try using div{vh =70%;} // window height.

Comment: Works like a beauty! Thanks, Careen!